# what is the meaning of 1 in user status field of wp_users in wordpress CMS?

Tags: wordpress

We are using wordpress for your website development. User is active when user_status=2 and user is inactive if user_status=0. Then what is the meaning of user_status=1.

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 13):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-status-of-user_status

> The user_status field is effectively a *dead* record in the database.
>   It's been that way for some time.
>
> You could certainly make use of it for your own purpose, but as it is
>   a sort of deprecated or unusued element, it's always possible it will
>   be dropped from a future version of WordPress. Or even be put back to
>   work.

Unfortunately, WordPress doesn't provide native online/offline user status methods. You'll have to implement it by yourself.
Some ideas how to implement it right, could be found in that topic:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/34429/44533

Another option is to use some 3rd-party plugin ( I can't advice any...).

In my own solution, I'm creating `user_login` custom filed in [wp_usermeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta) table, to check user status.

```
//Creating hooks for login/logout actions:
add_action('clear_auth_cookie', array('WP_Plugin_Template','set_user_logged_out'), 10);
add_action('wp_login', array('WP_Plugin_Template','set_user_logged_in'), 10, 2);

//When hook is triggered, I'm using user_meta to update user status:
function set_user_logged_in($user_login, $user) {
    if(get_user_meta($user->ID, "logged_in", true) !== "true")
    if(!update_user_meta($user->ID, 'logged_in', 'true'))
    wp_die("Failed to add usermeta ", "Fatal");
}
function set_user_logged_out() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(get_user_meta($user->ID, "logged_in", true) !== "false")
    if(!update_user_meta($user->ID, 'logged_in', 'false'))
    wp_die("Failed to add usermeta ", "Fatal");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  We are in a openion like usre-status field only decides the user activity. If we want to inactive a user, we made the user_status=2. If this field not decides weather user is active or not, then what is the responsible field ? Please provide your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Might i have asked my question wrongly. My question is how to restrict a user from registration. If i want to block a particular user, how to do it. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: It actually an answer :) . You should implement it by yourself by managing current user status. See the code above, you'll need wp_login hook to check if user have permissions to login or should be blocked.

Comment: There is also lightweight plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-users/ - will block an existing user from logging in

Answer (score 4):

From other threads I see that user_status is effectively a "dead" field. It remains in the wp_user table, but isn't used by WP itself for anything anymore. Probably explains why wp_update_user doesn't touch it.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('UPDATE wp_users SET user_status = 1 WHERE ID = '.$current_user->ID);
```

FOR MORE 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Might i have asked my question wrongly. My question is how to restrict a user from registration. If i want to block a particular user, how to do it. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: is should be user name or user roll(roll mean like subcriber,editer)

Comment: restrict by user. Not by role. your suggestions would help me a lot.

Comment: i hope this will be help http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/build-a-wordpress-plugin-to-restrict-content-to-registered-user/

Answer (score 4):

I might be late here but the user_status is not dead as it sounds, it is used mosty in network/multisite to mark user as spam ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here are what each user_status means:

> user_status = 0 => **false** or normal status
>
> user_status = 1 => User marked as **spammer**
>
> user_status = 2 => User **pending** (*user account not activated yet*)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `add_user_meta` ([WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)) and add a new field to your users table.

Seems like the cleanest way to me and you won´t be surprised, if `user_status` gets dropped from the database some time in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I agree with you. Please suggest me how to block a user from registration. We made user_status=2 till now to block a user.

Comment: You could use a hook on `wp_login` to run a custom function on login. This function could check your user defined user meta field which could be set via a function which is hooked on `user_register` (runs when a user is created) itself...

Answer (score 0):

> The user_status is not dead as it sounds, it is used mostly in
>   network/multisite to mark the user as spam or ham.
>
> This field is mostly used in multisite

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_status/