# how to inactivate user in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to inactivate a user in wordpress and block him from login. I have updated user_status is 2 in wp_users table. And it is working fine. But the following article shows that user_status has no value in wordpress.
[link]https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-status-of-user_status

So, can you suggest how to inactivate a user block him from login

Comment: try to avoid updating the core tables, you can use add_user_meta, get_user_meta for saving additional info

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the meaning of 1 in user status field of wp\_users in wordpress CMS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160327/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-in-user-status-field-of-wp-users-in-wordpress-cms)

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. Your article from yesterday had some good answers, did you try anything of that?

Answer (score 0):

Use word press plugin [Account Locker Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/account-locker-lite/) which provide facilities for block user with out delete user account in word press and inactivate a user block him from logging.

Answer (score 0):

The user_status field is effectively a *dead* record in the database. It’s been that way for some time.

You could certainly make use of it for your own purpose, but as it is a sort of deprecated or unusued element, it’s always possible it will be dropped from a future version of WordPress. Or even be put back to work.

Based on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-status-of-user_status